# Go use channel to alternated print

Tags: go

I want my code to print:

```
12AB34CD56EF78GH910IJ
```

but it prints:

```
12AB3456CDEF78910GHIJ
```

I am so confused and I think it is strange.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    numdone := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            data := []byte("ABCDEFGHIJ")
            for i := 0; i < 10; i = i + 2 {
                    <-numdone
                    fmt.Printf("%c", data[i])
                    fmt.Printf("%c", data[i+1])
            }
    }()

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for i := 1; i < 11; i = i + 2 {
                    fmt.Printf("%d", i)
                    fmt.Printf("%d", i+1)
                    numdone <- i
            }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: I have used a channel to guarantee output order, and the output is not as expected.

Comment: Your go routine #1 reads the channel but before it could print it go routine #2 is scheduled and prints the next set of numbers so you see 3456 in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Please read my comment above. To synchronize, just use a mutex and it'll work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var mu sync.Mutex

func main() {
    numdone := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        data := []byte("ABCDEFGHIJ")
        for i := 0; i < 10; i = i + 2 {
            <-numdone
            fmt.Printf("%c", data[i])
            fmt.Printf("%c", data[i+1])
            mu.Unlock()
        }
    }()

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 1; i < 11; i = i + 2 {
            mu.Lock()
            fmt.Printf("%d", i)
            fmt.Printf("%d", i+1)
            numdone <- i
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Playground : https://play.golang.org/p/71Dv0iKTy_

Comment: It really works,and I just find it can be done by two channel.thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, reading the second channel after the print in the first go routine. However you may want to keep the code easy to read and understand, so using a mutex may be a better choice.

Comment: Good one, gave +1 for this :)